# Parse JSON Result in C#?

Tags: javascript, c#

Here is my sample JSON :

```
{[
  {
    "DestinationCode": "ALCAN",
    "DestinationText": "Alaska"
  },
  {
    "DestinationCode": "FARE",
    "DestinationText": "Asia"
  },
  {
    "DestinationCode": "AUSTL",
    "DestinationText": "Australia/New Zealand"
  },
  {
    "DestinationCode": "BAHAM",
    "DestinationText": "Bahamas"
  },
  {
    "DestinationCode": "BERMU",
    "DestinationText": "Bermuda"
  },
  {
    "DestinationCode": "ATLCO",
    "DestinationText": "Canada/New England"
  },      
]}
```

and i am using below code to read :

```
var objects = JArray.Parse(Result); // parse as array  
foreach (JObject root in objects)
{
   root.
   string s = (String)root.Value["DestinationCode"];

   foreach (KeyValuePair<String, JToken> app in root)
   {

       var description = (String)app.Value["DestinationCode"];
       var value = (String)app.Value["DestinationText"];


       Console.WriteLine(description);
       Console.WriteLine(value);
       Console.WriteLine("\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: Telling us what your code does is ***not*** a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something more simple.

First, we have to define a class that represents your data.

```
public class Destination
{
    public string DestinationCode { get; set; }
    public string DestinationText { get; set; }
}
```

Then you have to parse the JSON like below:

```
var destinations = JsonConvert.Deserialize<IEnumerable<Destination>>(Result);
```

Last, you could consume your result like below:

```
foreach(var destination in destinations)
{
    Console.WriteLine(destination.Description);
    Console.WriteLine(destination.Text);
    Console.WriteLine("\n");
}
```

Comment: thanks .. it works for me after change this line 

var destinations = JsonConvert.Deserialize<IEnumerable<Destination>>(Result);

with 

  var destinations = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Destination>>(Result);

Comment: Might sound obvious, but for the convenience of those new to JSON in C#, you'll need to add `using Newtonsoft.Json;` (and for the original post, `using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;`)

Comment: @vinodsaini you are welcome dude. I am glad that I helped :)